# Does using dynamic library saving memory

Tags: c++, dll

As the title shows, can multiple processes share the same copy of dynamic library in memory?

I read [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815065/what-is-a-dll). Please search **Uses fewer resources** . The article said "a DLL can reduce the duplication of code that is loaded on the disk and in physical memory". I can understand the saving of disk space. While I'm not sure about the saving of "physical memory" when using DLL. Does the using of .so in Unix have the same advantage of saving memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the kernel only needs to load the physical code pages once and they can be shared by all processes regardless of where in each process the library gets loaded to. The PLT and GOT will be custom for each process but the .text section pages can be shared.

Comment: A detail: processes run in virtual memory and have their own virtual address space. The kernel don't "load the physical code",  it provides [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) and maps the code segment in a shared way. Some pages of the code segment (e.g. those of unused routines) might never go into RAM.

Comment: OK. And Unix and Windows work the same way in this regards, right?

Comment: Relocations complicate this slightly, but in general it's true.

Comment: (Note: Windows32 DLLs aren't position-independent-code, they are relocated when they are loaded into memory, so you might not save memory using them.)

Answer (score 1):

The kernel will load once and would be shared by other processes.

I have performed different test-
a) Compiled the sample program on different Linux servers:
gcc -rdynamic -o foo foo.c -ldl

```
    #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       #include <dlfcn.h>

       int
       main(int argc, char **argv)
       {
           void *handle;
           double (*cosine)(double);
           char *error;

           handle = dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
           if (!handle) {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

           /* Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
 *               would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
 *                             casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
 *                                           The assignment used below is the POSIX.1-2003 (Technical
 *                                                         Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale for the
 *                                                                       POSIX specification of dlsym(). */

           *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");

           if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
               fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           printf("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
           getchar();
           dlclose(handle);
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
```

The program can be found in manual pages - "man dlopen"

2) execute the command to see memory map for two PID from different interactive shells, (this can also be done using code)
ps -fu 
pmap -x

3) Compare the contents of output for two libraries-
 libdl-2.12.so //Static linking
 libm-2.12.so  //Loading using code

The address where it Memory map would be referring to should be same.

P.S. - Details can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116327/loading-of-shared-libraries-and-ram-usage)